# Check and show all options in a select

Tags: jquery

I am writing a statement so that if an option in the select contains something, do something.

I'm having issues on the way to deliver this outcome.

Essentially 1 product can have man, woman and kid, another could have man and woman. So im trying to create a statement in jquery to check the select options and if the options are available, show all the available options only, in the below case, show radio buttons man and woman

My first attempt below would only show the selected option id on load and thats all

```
        if($("#SingleOptionSelector").val() == "Man"){
           $('#Man').show(); 
        }
        if($("#SingleOptionSelector").val() == "Woman"){
           $('#Woman').show(); 
        }
```

My second attempt below works great by showing the id but it wouldnt work if I had more than 1 statement. So if I deleted either it worked, but if I kept both it didnt work.

```
        if(!$('#SingleOptionSelector').find("option:contains('" + Man + "')").length){
            $('#Man').show(); 
        }
        if(!$('#SingleOptionSelector').find("option:contains('" + Woman + "')").length){
            $('#Woman').show(); 
        }
```

HTML

```
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="properties[Human]" class="background-choices-selector"
                    value="Man" />
                <img id="Man" src="https://www.colorhexa.com/9d1d20.png">
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="properties[Human]" class="background-choices-selector"
                    value="Woman" />
                <img id="Woman" src="https://www.colorhexa.com/f49ac2.png">
            </label>
```

Liquid +  HTML

```
                {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
                <div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item">
                    <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input"
                        id="SingleOptionSelector" data-name="{{ option.name }}" data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}">
                        {% for value in option.values %}
                        <option value="{{ value | escape }}" {% if option.selected_value == value %} selected="selected"
                            {% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

FYI I've hidden the selector and linked it to radio inputs. I know it isn't ideal but I am linking it to the Shopify select product options

Comment: Add your html as well.

Comment: Hi @Swati added.

Comment: Hi what do you mean by `a person could choose 1, 2 and 6..` ? You can select mutliple options from select-box and where are these option i.e : `man,women` stored?

Comment: @Swati, woops got confused scratch that comment, essentially what ive done was hidden the select option field as it's part of shopifys liquid product variants

I've linked it to visible radio buttons which what im trying to do is show only the types that are available.

1 product can have man, woman and kid, another could have man and woman. So im trying to create a statement in jquery to check the select option and if the options are available, show i.e. in the top case, show radio buttons man and woman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understand this correctly; you want to check all the options and determine what fields to show based on *available* options and not just the *selected*

```js
$(document)
    .ready(function(){

        // this should be the select element
        $('#SingleOptionSelector')
            .children() // .children = options
            .each(function(){
                // note if the <option> does not have the attr: value="" then you may need to use $(this).text() instead
                switch($(this).val()){
                    case "man":
                        $('#Man').show();
                        break;

                    case "woman":
                        $('#Woman').show();
                        break;
                }
            });
    });
```

**ES6**

```js
$(document)
    .ready(() => {

        // this should be the select element
        $('#SingleOptionSelector')
            .children() // .children = options
            .each((index, element) => {
                // note if the <option> does not have the attr: value="" then you may need to use $(element).text() instead
                switch($(element).val()){
                    case "man":
                        $('#Man').show();
                        break;

                    case "woman":
                        $('#Woman').show();
                        break;
                }
            });
    });
```